# Initializing then updating textarea value in redux app.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, textarea

Inside my render function I have

```
     <textarea value={ this.props.song.client_lyrics }
               onKeyUp={ (event) => this.props.editLyrics(event.target.value) } >
     </textarea>
```

Normally the editLyrics function will dispatch an action which updates the client_lyrics. But since I have value = { this.props.song.client_lyrics } instead of event.target.value sending the initial value + what I typed, it only keeps sending over the original client_lyrics which just keeps setting client_lyrics to itself.

How can I initialize the textarea with a value and then append more characters to it so the client_lyrics prop actually changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of an `onChange` instead of an `onKeyUp` event on the `textArea`

```
  <textarea value={ this.props.song.client_lyrics }
           onChange={ (event) => this.props.editLyrics(event.target.value) } >
 </textarea>
```